# creating multiple nodes in a linked list beginner

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
typedef struct LinkedListItem
{
    int Number;
    LinkedListItem* Next;


    LinkedListItem(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
        Next = NULL;
    }
} LinkedListItem;

LinkedListItem *head = NULL;

head = new LinkedListItem(1);
head->Next = new LinkedListItem(2);  //confusing
head->Next->Next = new LinkedListItem(3);  //confusing
```

Hello. I am a beginner learning about linked list. This is a piece of code I found. I understand everything up until the lines I marked above. I understand that the head pointer is set to NULL first so then it can later point to a new LinkedListItem.

for

```
head->Next = new LinkedListItem(2)
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? I know that the arrow means to dereference. My guess is that dereferencing Next?

Answer (score 1):

Those lines add new elements to the list by creating a new item and recording it's address in the pointer `*Next`. So `head->Next` refers to the next element in the list. Once this is created then you can add `head->Next->Next`.

```
LinkedListItem *head = NULL;
```

head = NULL

```
head = new LinkedListItem(1);
```

head { Number = 1, Next = NULL }

```
head->Next = new LinkedListItem(2);
```

head { Number = 1, Next = { Number = 2, Next = NULL } }

```
head->Next->Next = new LinkedListItem(3);
```

head { Number = 1, Next = { Number = 2, Next = { Number = 3, Next = NULL } }

Answer (score 0):

When you say dereferencing it generally means `*head` in your piece of example. However if you write `head->Next` it is equivalent to `(*head).Next` so in that sense it is dereferencing.

As for your question, yes it is dereferencing head and adding new nodes at the end of the linked list. However be aware that this is not the neatest way to add elements to linked list. Even though it depends upon the type of application you are using linked list for, most generally you add elements directly to the head. Or keep a tail pointer and add to tail.

Comment: You have a typo, `head->Next` is actually equivalent to `(*head).Next`

Answer (score 0):

The

```
head->Next = new LinkedListItem(2)
```

statement is equivalent to

```
(*head).Next = new LinkedListItem(2)
```

so you dereference head and assign to its Next element (which is a pointer) a 
pointer to a new LinkedListItem.

Answer (score 0):

A **linked list** is a sequence of elements connected to each other via pointers.
In your example `Next` pointer points to a next element in list.
**Dereferencing** a pointer means to refer to an object a pointer points to.
An **arrow** means accessing fields of an object a pointer points to.

```
LinkedListItem *head = NULL;
```

In this line `head` pointer is set to `NULL`, as you correctly understood.

```
head = new LinkedListItem(1);
```

In this line `head` is set to point to a newly created `LinkedListItem`. `head->Number` is set to 1 and `head->Next` is set to NULL (see constructor).

```
head->Next = new LinkedListItem(2);
```

In this line new `LinkedListItem` is created and `Next` pointer of a `LinkedListItem` created in a previous line is set to point at it.

```
head->Next->Next = new LinkedListItem(3);
```

Just like in a previous line a new element is created and `Next` pointer of previous element is set to point at it.